# Problema com javascript e html no projeto do intellij

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, play-framework

Criei o arquivo index.js que é composto pelo código javascript abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu").accordion({collapsible: true, active: false});
});
```

e o botei juntamente com o jquery-2.1.1.min.js dentro da pasta javascripts do projeto do play framework e intellij e queria usar em conjunto com um código index.html que está na pasta app->views do projeto, mas não consigo como faço para usar o código de javascript em conjunto com o código html do index.html?

[image: imagem da composição do projeto:]

Comment: Em que pasta está esse `index.js`? só vejo um `hello.js` Não basta juntar `<script src="caminho/nomeFicheiro.js"></script>
`no HTML depois do jQuery?

Comment: É o hello.js, tirei esse print antes de alterar o nome para index. Tentei fazer isso mas não funciona.

Comment: Teste `<script src="/javascripts/index.js"></script>` para o `index.js` e `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` para o jQuery